# Code works in AS7(JBoss) but not Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

Code works in AS7(JBoss) but not Tomcat 7.  I am working on a Spring MVC project and I need to access the header and footer from a diff project so I insert the follow code in my JSP and it works great on JBoss but not on tomcat7

```
<c:import url="/webapphead.jsp" context="/common" />
```

this is the error I am getting in tomcat:

```
2013-03-22 08:46:54,942 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Unable to get RequestDispatcher for Context: "/common" and URL: "/webapphead.jsp". Verify values and/or enable cross context access.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `crossContext` to `true`? Check the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes).